# Uploading to pypi without credentials in .pypirc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypi

I want to upload a package to `pypi` without storing my credentials in plaintext in `.pypirc`.

I checked out the documentation: https://www.afpy.org/doc/python/2.7/distutils/packageindex.html#the-upload-command

> If a register command was previously called in the same command, and
>   if the password was entered in the prompt, upload will reuse the
>   entered password. This is useful if you do not want to store a
>   password in clear text in a .pypirc file.

I tried running `python setup.py register bdist_wheel upload`. I get prompted for my credentials, enter them, and the register succeeds. When it tries to upload, I get the following error:

```
Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
error: Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
```

What am I missing?